# How to add custom title for the web-browser tab in the Swagger YAML root file using with Connexion Python?

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, connexion

So I have this Swagger UI which I built using YAML config and I am using it with Connexion Python. How do I change the title of the page which has been circled in red marker?

[image]

I have tried googling out stuff, but seems like, there are no answers for users of Connexion or Swagger YAML. Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swagerDoc, { customSiteTitle: "Your title" }));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).